# Retrieving selected cells on a given grid using Python

Tags: python

I have a grid on which user clicks and selects a range

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1  J1  K1  L1
A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2  H2  I2  J2  K2  L2
A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3  G3  H3  I3  J3  K3  L3
A4  B4  C4  D4  E4  F4  G4  H4  I4  J4  K4  L4
A5  B5  C5  D5  E5  F5  G5  H5  I5  J5  K5  L5
A6  B6  C6  D6  E6  F6  G6  H6  I6  J6  K6  L6
A7  B7  C7  D7  E7  F7  G7  H7  I7  J7  K7  L7
A8  B8  C8  D8  E8  F8  G8  H8  I8  J8  K8  L8
A9  B9  C9  D9  E9  F9  G9  H9  I9  J9  K9  L9
```

The user selection is always a rectangle or a square.  For example, if the user select's a rectangle J8-L9, the the only data that is returned is J8:L9.
In this case the user has selected six boxes in the grid viz J8,K8, L8, J9, K9 and L9.  These are the six boxes that I want to retrieve as a result.   On other instances, the user might just select A4:C4, which essentially has only one row, but has three cells.  How could I retrieve all the cells that is within the range using Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know 2 corner of your rectangle:

```
top_left=J8
bottom_right=L9
```

you can get:

```
top=J
bottom=L
left=8
right=9
```

then you can index your dataframe like this:

```
df.loc[top:bottom, left:right]
```

Comment: Thank you....This really helped...I understand R data.frames and subsets but have very little exposure to python and just got flummoxed initially...just learnt the pythonic way of subsetting a dataframe...through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvpNA7bC8cs  Thank you again